# Hashing using SHA1 as inner-most hash in a chain

Tags: encryption, cryptography, sha

A client program (over which I have no control) is authenticating by sending me a password, hashed as `SHA1(password)`.

I'm reluctant to store the password hashed using only SHA1 in my database, so I'm proposing to store passwords in the database hashed as `SHA256(SHA1(password))` (where the password is hashed over multiple iterations using PBKDF-2 or something similar).

My question is: is there anything insecure about the inner-most hash using SHA1 in this scenario? I realise that the probability of collisions will be increased, but since this is just for storing passwords in the database I don't think I need to be concerned about that. Is there anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: For a (probably) more correct answer to this question, try http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding a salt which is unique-per-row before doing the final encryption. Example:

Lets say that you receive `W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g=` (a SHA1'd encryption of `"password"`). That is associated with a User, who should have a unique key, such as a UserID and/or UserName.

My suggestion - to avoid collision - would be to do a conversion of the Bytes to a Base64String (in C# this would be `Convert.ToBase64String( byteVariable )` - then concatenate onto the string the user's unique-ID (making the new string something like:

`W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g=+103` (where I added `+103` to reflect the user's ID) - then apply your SHA256 algorithm. This will produce: `mNXRjWsKJ7V+BHbAuwJJ7neGT+V1IrLQSQXmb4Vv1X8=` - which you can store in your database. A SHA256 hash - which eliminates the collisions from the less-safe SHA1 algorithm.

And - since you are using 1-way encryption - when you go to check whether the password is valid in the future, you simply append the user's ID again before checking.

Comment: PBKDF-2 makes any expansion with base64 or anything else redundant. Adding a salt - whether it's the user's internal unique ID or something else immutable stored in their record - is always a good idea, though.

Comment: Deterministic data, such as User ID, is not a good choice for a Salt. Nor is inventing your own cryptosystem - this is why PBKDF2 and other password hashing primitives exist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'm wondering why I should care about whether I get collisions?

Comment: You really shouldn't - but you mentioned collisions in your question. The only real reason collisions would concern you was if someone was able to get access to your database and was attempting to crack the passwords. Collided password hashes would allow the hacker to find working passwords for multiple accounts at the same time. This is no worse than 2 users choosing the same password, though. The bigger benefit here is the addition of the salt to the hashes.

Answer (score 1):

If the client always sends you the same password, simply SHA1 hashed, then the SHA1 hash output *is* the password, to all intents and purposes. Treat it and store it the same way you would any other password, such as by using PBKDF2, SCrypt, or BCrypt.